# Duda para convertir código de Python a C

Tags: python, c

Estoy intentando transformar un código de `Python` a `C`, pero estoy teniendo problemas con la visualización al ejecutar el programa.

El código en `Python` es este:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

md2 = randint(1,30)

def make_tree():
  print('\033c')

  for x in range (1,30,2):
    md1 = randint(1,md2)
    if x==1:
      ch = "$"
    elif md1 % 4 == 0:
      ch = "o"
    elif md1 % 3 == 0:
      ch = "i"
    else:
      ch = "*"

    print ("{:^33}".format(ch*x))

  print ("{:^33}".format("|||"))
  print ("{:^33}".format("|||"))
  sleep(.75)

while True:
  make_tree()
```

La salida en `Python` se muestra algo así, ya que es en movimiento:

```
                $
               ***
              iiiii
             *******
            *********
           iiiiiiiiiii
          iiiiiiiiiiiii
         ***************
        *****************
       *******************
      *********************
     ***********************
    *************************
   ***************************
  *****************************
               |||
               |||
```

Y este mismo programa lo quiero hacer en `C`, pero no se como adaptarlo al 100%.

Tengo esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void make_tree(void);

int main(){

    while(1){
        make_tree();
    }

    return 0;
}

void make_tree(void){
    int random = rand () % (30 - 1 + 1) + 1;  
    char character; 
    int i;

    printf("\033c");

    for( i = 1; i < 23; i++){
        int random2 = rand() % (random - 1 + 1) + 1; 

        if( i == 1 )
            character = '$';
        else if( random2 % 4 == 0) 
            character = 'o';
        else if( random2 % 3 == 0 )
            character = 'i';
        else
            character = '*';

        printf("%c\n", character);
    }

    printf("|||\n");
    printf("|||");
    sleep(3);
}
```

Pero el `printf()` no sale como se espera.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que hay un par de cosas que no has entendido del código python:

- El bucle que imprime cada fila del árbol avanza de 2 en 2, ya que se usa `range(1,30,2)`. En cambio el tuyo va de 1 en 1, pues usas `for (i=0;i<23;i++)`. Aparte de que solo llegas a 23 en vez de 30, el incremento de `i` debería ser `i+=2` para que se comporte como python.
- Y lo más importante, el `print()` que muestra cada fila del árbol, en python usa la cadena de formato `{:^33}`, que significa "centrar en una cadena de ancho 33" (para lo cual añadirá espacios a los lados), y lo que se imprime es `ch*x`, que significa "el carácter `ch` repetido `x` veces.

  En cambio tu código C simplemente imprime `printf("%c\n", ch)` por lo que el carácter se imprimirá una sola vez en lugar de `x` veces (en tu caso sería `i` la variable que dice cuántas veces debe repetirse el carácter), y además no se centra la línea para que ocupe un ancho de 33.

La forma más sencilla de arreglar esto será escribir una función en C que reciba como parámetros el carácter a mostrar, cuántas veces debe repetirse ese carácter, y el ancho de la línea en la cual debe aparecer "centrado" el resultado. Esta función imprimirá primero el número de espacios necesarios para "centrar" el resultado, después el carácter repetido tantas veces como se le pida, y por último de nuevo la cantidad de espacios necesaria para rellenar hasta el final de la línea.

La función podría ser así:

```c
void print_linea(char ch, int repeat, int width){
    int pad = (width-repeat)/2;
    for (int i=0; i<pad; i++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for (int i=0; i<repeat; i++) {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<pad; i++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Y tu programa la usaría así:

```
void make_tree(void){
    int random = rand () % (30 - 1 + 1) + 1;
    char character;
    int i;

    printf("\033c");

    for( i = 1; i < 23; i+=2){
        int random2 = rand() % (random - 1 + 1) + 1;

        if( i == 1 )
            character = '$';
        else if( random2 % 4 == 0)
            character = 'o';
        else if( random2 % 3 == 0 )
            character = 'i';
        else
            character = '*';
        print_linea(character, i, 33);
    }
    print_linea('|', 3, 33);
    print_linea('|', 3, 33);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Fíjate cómo he aprovechado la función `print_linea()` también para pintar el tronco del árbol, repitiendo 3 veces el carácter `|`.

El resultado es:

[image: resultado]

Answer (score 1):

Una posible implementación en C sería ésta:

```
int main()
{
   while(1){
   make_tree();
}
    return 0;
}

void make_tree(void){
        int random = rand () % (30 - 1 + 1) + 1;                     
        char character;
        char line[61];
        int i;
        int x;

        for( i = 0; i < 61; i++) line[i] = ' ' ;

        printf("\033c");

        for( i = 1; i < 30; i=i+2){
                int random2 = rand() % (random - 1 + 1) + 1; 

                if( i == 1 )
                {
                        character = '$';
                }
                else 
                {
                        if( random2 % 4 == 0) 
                                character = 'o';
                        else if( random2 % 3 == 0 )
                                character = 'i';
                        else
                                character = '*';

                        line[31] = character;
                        for( x=0; x<i/2; x++) 
                        {
                                line[31+x] = character; 
                                line[31-x] = character;
                        }
                        printf("%s\n", line);
                }

        }

        printf("%33s\n","|||");
        printf("%33s\n","|||");
        sleep(3);
}
```